# before save callback for boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The before_save callback should update expired field value to `true` or `false` based on the code below:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_availabiltiy

  def update_availabiltiy
    self.expired = date_end.to_date < Date.today
  end
end
```

but it won't work unless the value of this field is the same as stored one, in example: if this field is true in DB and the condition in callback will evaluate to true, record will be saved, otherwise controller will return 400

```
Started PUT "/api/venues/bogan-and-sons/packages/delicious-package" for ::1 at 2016-09-20 15:20:03 +0300
Processing by Api::PackagesController#update as JSON

Parameters: {"package"=>
  {"date_start"=>"2016-08-27T00:00:00.000-04:00", "date_end"=>"2016-12-30, ...}
}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 400 Bad Request in 81ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 17.8ms)
```

object.errors returns empty array, so no actual error on object is present.

**Update for Andrey:**

```
[31, 40] in /Users/srosca/projects/venuezz/app/models/package.rb
   31:     !expired || (Date.today <= self.date_end.to_date)
   32:   end
   33: 
   34:   def update_availabiltiy
   35:     byebug
=> 36:     self.expired = date_end.to_date < Date.today
   37:   end
   38: 
   39:   def calculate_discount
   40:     if discount_price
(byebug) expired
true
(byebug) date_end.to_date < Date.today
false
(byebug) self.expired = date_end.to_date < Date.today
false
(byebug) expired
false
```

Comment: show the whole `package` params please

Comment: Use ruby's 'strftime' method to format them to be the same in your callback and then compare.

Comment: also, to see the real problem add bang to the method: `save!` or `update!`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko will it matter? if I remove this callback the object will save just fine.
Added the ! sign on update_attributes, will update my post.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko just for the sake of saving the space here, I added full logs on gist https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/b599de7baca2da43644a48e0bbfc409e

Comment: change `update` to `update!` here `app/controllers/api/packages_controller.rb` and show what that says ;)

Comment: @bkunzi01 why? they are both date objects, date_end.to_date and Date.today, tried with debugger and it returns true or false, depends on the param.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - see the link in comments above https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/b599de7baca2da43644a48e0bbfc409e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `before_save` hooks have the ability to cancel save operation by returning `false` (which is what happens when your record is not expired.

Return something else, not result of the assignment. For example:

```
  def update_availabiltiy
    self.expired = date_end.to_date < Date.today

    true # no canceling
  end
```